# Show that $f(x)$ cant be written like this

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> For $n>1$ let $a_1$, $a_2$, $\ldots$, $a_n$ be $n$ distinct integers. Prove that the polynomial $$f(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_n)-1$$ cannot be written as $g(x)h(x)$ where $g$ and $h$ are nonconstant polynomials with integer coefficients.

Please confirm this:

> The negation would be,
>
> $f(x)$ can be written as $g(x)\cdot h(x)$ where $g, h$ are constant polynomial with fractional coefficients right?
>
> $$f(x) = \alpha \beta = (x - a_1)(x - a_2)\cdots(x - a_n) - 1 $$
>
> This is automatically impossible since that implies,
>
> $$x^n + .... + a_0 = \alpha \cdot \beta$$
>
> Having no $x$ on the RHS?

If the above is *incorrect,* instead of a solution, can you tell me the proper negation or another idea?

Thanks!

Comment: The negation should be exactly the same statement except the "cannot" changed to "can".

Comment: @KittyL, not exactly.  The distinction can be seen in another problem, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302451/consider-the-two-statements-all-rhombi-are-squares-and-no-rhombi-are-squares -- which, curiously, resurfaced (courtesy of a spurious, spam answer) at around the time this question was posted.

Comment: @BarryCipra In this case it works.

Comment: @BarryCipra: This is not exactly the same case as that.

Comment: @wythagoras, I'm not sure what you mean.  The original statements is, essentially, of the form "for all $f$ you cannot...," so the proper negation would be "for some $f$ you can...," not "for all $f$ you can...."

Comment: @KittyL, I disagree.  Both cases are incorrectly negating a statement $\forall x(P(x))$ into $\forall x(\lnot P(x))$.

Comment: @BarryCipra: With different $a_1, a_2, ...,a_n$ and $n$? I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negation is not correct. Indeed, the correct negation is given by:

There exists a polynomial $f(x)=(x−a_1)(x−a_2)⋯(x−a_n)−1$ that can be written as $g(x)h(x)$ where $g$ and $h$ are nonconstant polynomials with integer coefficients.

**Hint:** Now compare the degrees of $g$ and $h$. What happens if the degree of one of both is smaller than $\frac{n}{2}$. What happens if they are both exactly $\frac{n}{2}$?

Comment: How do you find the correct negation in general given several constraints? (+1)

Comment: When the original is "Show that....can't...." you simply change "can't" to "can".